# Gmail Label Conversation that were initiated by me

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-search

[image: I need to apply label on only those conversations that were started by me]

I need to apply label on only those conversations that were started by me.

In the image attached, those conversations having the words (representing senders' nicknames) "me, Mail 2" means this conversation contains 2 emails with 'me' as the first email composer and 'Mail' as the second email composer.

Whereas "Pending, me 2" means this conversation contains 2 emails with 'Pending' as the first email composer and 'me' as the second email composer.

Please note that I already have a filter for emails I reply to with label called R.
Please note that I already have a filter for emails I forward with label called F.

[image: Filter description of Reply and Forward]

It would be great to integrate the freshly sent mails by me without breaking R and F labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a really simple answer myself after some brainstorming

Matches: (from:myemail@gmail.com -(subject:fwd: OR subject:re:))

Do this: Apply label "S"

I noticed a particular existing (prior to creating filter) email conversation initiated by me which was forwarded to someone later by myself but is not showing with this search filter criteria, though the label was still applied which is having the same filter criteria.
As I have noticed from time to time, gmail does have miniscule probability of throwing bugs with searching specific things when conversation mode is turned on.